# Not sure how to use intents on heroku server

Tags: python, discord.py

I have everything working when I run my discord bot on my computer, but when I upload my code into heroku. I get this error message.

```
2020-12-08T22:37:37.551623+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-08T22:37:37.551649+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 22, in <module>
2020-12-08T22:37:37.551751+00:00 app[worker.1]: intents = discord.Intents.default()
2020-12-08T22:37:37.551756+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'
```

I'm not sure if I forgot to add something to my requirements folder or something, but everything works fine on my pc.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

This is my requirements:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
requests
python-dotenv
gTTS
opuslib
asyncio
youtube-dl
discord
discord.py[voice] ~= 1.4.0
pip
ffmpeg
google-cloud-firestore
firebase-admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.py Intents require version 1.5+ (see [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)), you have version 1.4.x.    To fix this issue, just update `requirements.txt` to a compatible version.

Side note: Why do you have discord.py listed 3 times in `requirements.txt` and include `asyncio`, which has been in the stdlib since 3.4?

Comment: Thank you so much, I just copied my requirements file from a youtube video. That video was probably really outdated.